# Python - substitute inplace - removing .bak backup files with close()?

Tags: python

When I run the following script, a .bak backup file is left in the filesystem.
How do I close() the files(s) properly so the backups are deleted?

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
import os
myRelease = os.environ.get("BUILD_STRING")
myVersion = os.environ.get("VERSION_STRING")
import fileinput
import re
files = ["C:\Projects\FileToSub.sbs"]
for line in fileinput.FileInput(files,inplace=1):
   line = re.sub('whatever, thing', line)
   print line,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fileinput` module takes care about deleting the backup files.

I'm not completely sure what you tested, but your python code contains errors. A 'guessed' and 'corrected' version:

```
import fileinput
import re
files = ["FileToSub1.sbs", "FileToSub2.sbs"]
for line in fileinput.FileInput(files, inplace=1):
    line = re.sub('whatever', 'thing', line)
    print line,
```

In the strace output you can see, that the files are automagically removed:

```
unlink("FileToSub2.sbs.bak")            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rename("FileToSub2.sbs", "FileToSub2.sbs.bak") = 0
open("FileToSub2.sbs.bak", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
open("FileToSub2.sbs", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0100644) = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8001 (flags O_WRONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdf3a988000
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
chmod("FileToSub2.sbs", 0100644)        = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdf3a987000
read(3, "whatever\nfile\nthing\nline\nwhas\n", 8192) = 30
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
write(4, "thing\nfile\nthing\nline\nwhas\n", 27) = 27
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fdf3a988000, 4096)            = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fdf3a987000, 4096)            = 0
unlink("FileToSub2.sbs.bak")            = 0
```

Comment: But the backup file still exists for me!
Maybe it is because I am running a python script in jenkins?

Comment: Can you add the `strace` output to the question?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how!  Can you give me an idiot's guide please?

Comment: I don't know if there is an strace equivalent for Windows. Maybe you can use this: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/Strace%20NT.shtml

Comment: check this page too: http://kohei.us/2010/06/25/strace-equivalent-for-windows/ :)

Comment: I suspect I know the problem.
I didn't svn lock the file beforehand so it starts off read-only.
python then creates a read-only backup and can't automagically delete it.

Answer (score 2):

you can call the [close](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) method, e.g.

myfile.close()

Why don't you remove the file using the [os.remove](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove)? You can do this:

```
import os

# call this after the end of your script
os.remove("C:\Projects\FileToSub.subs.bak")
```

Comment: Currently ...
    import stat
    os.chmod("C:\Projects\FileToSub.sbs.bak",stat.S_IWRITE)  
    os.remove("C:\Projects\FileToSub.sbs.bak")`  

Seems to do the job but feels wrong.

Comment: maybe Andreas Florath is more close to what you want. See my comment to his answer!